# Using principal verb "has" as auxiliary verb

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs

1.How many children do you have?

2.How many children have you?

1.Does she have a boyfriend?

2.Has she a boyfriend?

1.Don't they have a TV?

2.Have they no TV ?

3.Haven't they a TV ?

Are all these sentences correct and mean the same thing?

Comment: They are all correct.  "Has she a boyfriend" and "Haven't they a TV" are typical in BrE if I'm not mistaken and sound "British" and/or very formal/fancy in AmE.

Comment: Yes, each pair has the same meaning. In those examples with "do", static "have" is a lexical verb, while in those without "do" it is an auxiliary verb. Most speakers treat this "have" as a lexical verb, even in BrE nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, all the sentence have different meanings, however, consecutive pairs of sentences have equal meaning.

1. How many children do you have? = How many children have you? = How many children have you got?
2. Does she have a boyfriend? = Has she a boyfriend? = Has she got a boyfriend?
3. Don't they have a TV? = Haven't they a TV? = Haven't they got a TV?

"**Have somebody no**" is a different kind of a declarative sentence often with a grain of astonishment or discontent *(Really? or Indeed!)*. Among popular quotes is "*Have you no sense of decency, sir?*”.

- Have you no sense of humor? - *What? Really? You don't, do you?*
- Have you no money then? - *Is it so? Indeed you don't, do you?*